# How to derive symmetry invariant terms in Hamiltonian from a space group?

Tags: symmetry, hamiltonian, representation-theory, crystals

If a space group of some crystal is know, how can we derive the Hamilton of it in spin form to do more theoretical calculations?

For example, for a space group No.5 (C2), whose generators are

1. $x,y,z$
2. $-x,y,-z$
3. $x+1/2,y+1/2,z$

How do we find all the symmetry invariant terms? What I know is we should use the same representation to represent the generators (e.g. spin form $S_x$,$S_y$,$S_z$), then find all possible terms that satisfy $[H,g]=0$, but I don't know to do this exactly. How to derive the spin form of these generators? And is there any more efficient way to find the allowed Hamiltonians terms? Since there are so many different possible combinations.

It will be appreciated if you can help or introduce any textbooks/papers about it.